# How do I handle, parse, a colon in the url with httparty and json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, httparty, mochi

I'm trying to parse the Mochi Media API on my site. Unfortunately, they make use of colons in their API URLs....

```
http://feedmonger.mochimedia.com/feeds/query/?q=(recommendation:>=0) and category:action&partner_id=XXXX
```

The question is, using httparty, how do I parse that url given that the :query/options hash will automatically convert to a standard query string:

```
get('/myNewApiUrl', :query => {:key => value}) | http://base/myNewApiUrl?key=value&key2=value2
```

I need something to handle this:

```
get('/myNewApiUrl', :query => {:key => value}) | http://base/myNewApiUrl?key:value&key2=value2
```

Can anyone help me out... just about ready to bang my head against a wall. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to solve this by using a variable that I then passed along to the httparty's get method.

i.e.

```
url = ["URL-UP-TO-/?query=CATEGORY:",category].join("")
get(url)
```

Hopefully this helps someone else looking to use httparty. The GEM is really impressive!